# My poweshell policy is overriden. What can i try to run my script?

Tags: powershell-3.0

i get a error if i want to try out my new powershell script on a new server. I allready edited the gpo and policys. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06F0P.png)

What else can i try?

Comment: Can you explain further what "i get a error" mean? Is there any message involved? How do you "try out" that script?

Comment: Thats from Powershell: "
if((get-ExecutionPolicy) -ne 'Allsigned') (Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process)
Categoryinfo :PermissionDenied: (:) (Set-ExecutionPolicy) SecurityExecution
FullyDeniedErrorID: ExecutionPolicyOverride.Microsoft.Powershell.Command.SetExecutionPoliceCommand
"

Scopes
MachinePolicy & UserPolicy = Unrestricted 
Process, Current User, LocalMachine = Bypass

Comment: Please add that to the question if it is relevant, not to the comment section. Also add what that should be